# reference parent object in javascript

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype, this, iife

I'm new to javascript and struggling with a problem below.

Let's think about this situation.

First, there is an object like this.

```
var bar = {
            'name' : 'bob',
            'comments' : []
          }
```

However because of some reasons, we have only one variable that named 'foo' and this is exactly same with `bar.comments`.

Second, because we need to reference the object `bar`, there must exist method in `foo`, named `callParent`. If we satisfy all these condition, we can get object `bar` using `foo.callParent()`.

To implement like above, first of all, I define a constructor name `Custom`.

```
function Custom(param){
    this.callParent = function(){
        console.log(param);
    }
}
```

and then, to use instance of `Custom` like array, inherit Array.

```
Custom.prototype = Array.prototype;
```

after that, I want to define object `bar` as like below.

```
var bar = {
            'name':'bob',
            'comments':new Custom(this)
          }
```

In that implementation, because I thought `this` means `bar` itself, I expected the result `foo.callParent()` will be `bar` but it was `window`. I think it's because in the context of calling `foo.callParent()`, `this` no longer means `bar`.

Finally, I solve this problem like this.

```
var bar = {
            'name':'bob',
            'comments':undefined,
            'init':function(){
                        this.comments = new Custom(this);
                        return this;
            }
}.init();
```

**Qeustion**: Is there any way to solve this situation without help of other method like `bar.init`? I want to solve this only with changes of constructor `Custom`! Is it related with **IIFE**?

Comment: Like this ? `var bar = {
            'name':'bob',
            'comments':new Custom(bar)
          }`

Comment: @tresden that won't work - that will pass `undefined`.

Comment: @DanielA.White Oh, my bad. It should've been similar to your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var bar = {
        'name':'bob'
      };
bar.comments = new Custom(bar);
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to solve it with `this` which is used as parameter of `Custom` ! :D

Comment: @HT.Cha that overly complicates things.